# What's the difference between "doesn't synthesize" and "defined as deleted"?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue-reference

I read C++ Primer 5th, and found move constructor and move assignment confusing.

On one page, it says:

> The compiler synthesizes the move constructor and move assignment only
>   if a class does not define any of its own copy-control members and
>   only if all the data members can be moved constructed and move
>   assigned, respectively.

On another page, it says:

> If we explicitly ask the compiler to generate a move operation by
>   using = default, and the compiler is unable to move all the members,
>   then the move operation will be defined as deleted.

Is there any difference between "doesn't synthesize" and "will be defined as deleted"?

Comment: A function defined as deleted still participates in overload resolution; if selected, the program is ill-formed. If a function does not exist at all, it of course doesn't participate in overload resolution.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you. How can I mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function defined as deleted still participates in overload resolution; if selected, the program is ill-formed. If a function does not exist at all, it of course doesn't participate in overload resolution.